# Targeting div from divs created with for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm working on creating divs into a parent div using a for loop. That works fine but I want to target one of the divs afterwards using an array.

My code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        var newTable = $('<div id="div' + i + '"></div').css({
            'width': tableSize.tableW + '%',
            'height': tableSize.tableH + '%',
            'background-color': 'black'
        });

        var tableProp = {
            'left': pos.posX,
            'top': pos.posY,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'display': 'none'
        };

        newTable.css(tableProp).appendTo('body').
        .delay(500, function() {});

        var availableTables = [$('#div' + [i] + '')];
    }
}
```

This is where I'm trying to store all the divs in the array `availableTables`

```
var availableTables = [$('#div' + [i] + '')];
```

But these just say it's undefined. How do I target a specific div from this array? I'm probably doing something wrong

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9180vsm/1/) with the code.

EDIT: Updated the fiddle link

Comment: _"I made a fiddle with the code"_ - or did you. In your fiddle, the line creating the div elements is `var newTable = $('<div id="hoi"></div').css(...` You can go looking for div elements with ids such as `div1`, `div2` etc for a long time, when you did not actually create a single one with such an id, but multiple ones with the same id `hoi` ...

Comment: Sorry! i edited the link a bit afterwards. I forgot that part. I will update the original question. Here is updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/m9180vsm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, declare availableTables outside of the loop. Then if you do something like

```
availableTables.push(newTable);
```

it should work. Your code will not work at all because

```
[$('#div' + [i] + '')]
```

should be

```
[$('#div' + i + '')]
```

this could do something, it will return an array of 1 element, where that element is your new div - but I don't think it's what you wanted

My suggestion is you should assign newTable.css(tableProp) to a new variable:

```
let newTableFinal = newTable.css(tableProp);
newTableFinal.appendTo('body');
availableTables.push(newTableFinal);
```

What I don't understand from your code is the use of that .delay(500, function(){}) function... Its saying "after 500ms, execute empty function, and then continue the execution queque" - but the execution quque is empty after the .delay call, and the function you execute is empty...

Also, I'm not super sure you need that assignment of newTableFinal, you might as well push into the array "newTable" or "$('#div' + i + '')".
Not "[$('#div' + i + '')]" because this would push into the array an array with one item wich contains an array of items selected by the jQuery selector... To many arrays of arrays :P

EDIT: just a quick note... If you plan on using "i" inside of the .delay callback, you should remember about how scoping works... Inside that delay callback "i" will almost always be equal to the values it has when exiting the loop! You should either turn "var i" into "let i", or use a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You have already been giving ID's for every div in the loop, which is good. So now you can simply trigger any div using its ID.

```
$(document).on('click', '#id1', function() {

   //Some Operation

});
```

You cannot simply use **$("#id1").click** when you are adding elements dynamically in a jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work.. all I have done is used class instead of id, and moved availableTables variable out of loop.

Issues

- Id's are unique, so shouldnt add them in a loop.

- As availableTables variable is inside loop, it kept replacing everytime with last div.

```html
<body>
    <input type="text" value="3">
    <br>
    <button id="input">Add divs</button>
    <script>
    $("#input").click(function() {
        x = [];
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            x.push($(this).val());
        });

        makeTable();
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    function makeTable() {
        var tableSize = {
            tableW: 10,
            tableH: 12
        };
        var pos = {
            posX: 0,
            posY: 100
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            var newTable = $('<div class="hoi"></div').css({
                'width': tableSize.tableW + '%',
                'height': tableSize.tableH + '%',
                'background-color': 'black'
            });
            var tableProp = {
                'left': pos.posX,
                'top': pos.posY,
                'position': 'absolute',
                'display': 'none'
            };

            pos.posX += 200;
            newTable.css(tableProp).appendTo('body').fadeIn(1000).delay(500, function() {});
            // $('#div' + [i] + '').css({'display': 'none'});
            // var availableTables = $('#mainDiv').children();
           
        }
         var availableTables = $('.hoi');
        console.log(availableTables);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I left out a crucial part of the fiddle. I updated it once again and your answer doens't cover the new version.